# Pandas merge multiple dataframes with lookup value stored on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, left-join

I would like to merge 2 dataframes where the lookup value is stored on multiple columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d1 = {'CODE': ['BBLGLC70M',np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
      'CODE1': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'AALGLC71P', np.nan],
      'CODE2': ['BBLG', np.nan, 'ZZTNRD77', 'PRI', np.nan],
      'DESC': ['OK', 'FALSE', 'YES', 'OK', 'NO']
       }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df1

df = {'NUMBER': ['BBLGLC70M', 'AALGLC71P', 'ZZTNRD77']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df
```

[image]

[image]

The code that I wrote outputs NaN in all fields:

```
merged = pd.merge(df, df1, how='left', left_on=['NUMBER', 'NUMBER', 'NUMBER'], right_on=['CODE', 'CODE1', 'CODE2'])
merged
```

[image]

I would expect to see all fileds populated for example for the first line I would expect:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge one by one for all columns and concat all these dataframes:

```
res_df = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df1.columns:
  temp_df = df.merge(df1, left_on=['NUMBER'], right_on=[col], how='inner')
  res_df = pd.concat([res_df, temp_df], axis=0)

print(res_df)
```

Output:

```
      NUMBER       CODE      CODE1     CODE2 DESC
0  BBLGLC70M  BBLGLC70M        NaN      BBLG   OK
0  AALGLC71P        NaN  AALGLC71P       PRI   OK
0   ZZTNRD77        NaN        NaN  ZZTNRD77  YES
```